# postMessage(...) is posting messages to window other than targetWindow

Tags: javascript, iframe, jestjs, postmessage

I am using [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between a parent `window` and a child `iframe`.  Currently, I only have the parent defined in a `jest` unit test.

When I post the message from the `iframe`, I only reference `window.parent` as my `targetWindow`:

```
window.parent.postMessage(myMessage, "*");
```

However, in my `iframe`'s message event handler, I am receiving the message even though my `iframe` is not `window.parent`.  I've also tried filtering these messages out by checking `event.source`, but `event.source` always appears to be `null`.

Is `jest` messing with my `window` definition causing the `iframe` and `parent` to be the same object?  What is happening here and how do I avoid it?

Comment: I haven't looked at this closely, but the default `Jest` environment is a browser-like environment provided by [`jsdom`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) and my guess is that `jsdom` doesn't provide a completely accurate implementation of `postMessage`

Comment: hmm good to know considering i was recommended to migrate to jsdom to solve this

Answer (score -1):

since it is unit testing you should test both sides separately against mocked postMessage, otherwise it seems like integration test to me.

```
window.postMessage = jest.fn();
```

happy coding :)